# Count total number of records in Rails join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, users and departments, and a join table users_departments to enable a has_and_belongs_to_many association between them. I am using PostgreSQL as the database.

```
# users table columns
id
name

# departments table columns
id
name

# users_departments table columns
user_id
department_id
```

What is the best way in Rails for counting the total number of records in the users_departments table? Preferably without creating a new model class.

Please note that I do not want to count the records for a specific user or department (user.departments.count / departments.users.count), but the total number records for the table, considering all users and departments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to just create a model called `UsersDepartment` and do a nice and easy query on that.

```rb
count = UsersDepartment.count
```

You can query the table directly however with [`exec_query`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_query) which gives you an [`ActiveRecord::Result`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html) object to play with.

```rb
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('select count(*) as count from users_departments')
count = result[0]['count']
```